# Does `Ctrl+S` on a webpage transfer the webpage data to my hard-disk using FTP?

Tags: networking, ftp

I am trying to understand more about how FTP works (Am new to the world of internet networking, so apologies if the style of my phrasing is awkward when talking about protocols). As I understand, FTP is used to transfer files from the internet from one computer to another. HTTP  on the other hand is just used to "view" / display webpages on another server.

Say, I go to [BBC.com](https://www.bbc.com/) and download the webpage with `Ctrl+S`. A bunch of associated media files (e.g. pictures) referenced in the page also get downloaded to a separate folder in my computer. Do *these* files get transferred using the FTP protocol? Does content of the webpage (i.e. the index.html file of the bbc website) also get downloaded with FTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be noted that what your browser does when you invoke the "Save" command (via the Ctrl-S/Cmd-S keyboard shortcut or otherwise), is completely up to your browser. There's no standard specifying what a browser should do when someone hits "Save".

Since you've already loaded the page, the browser has already downloaded all the files involved (HTML, CSS, JavaScript, web fonts, image files, etc.) via HTTP, and is already holding them in RAM if not also in an on-disk cache. So when you invoke "Save", it just copies those cached files to wherever you tell it to save the page.

Most web servers only expose HTTP to the public. Most are *not* FTP-accessible. So web browsers don't presume they can use FTP to retrieve any files from a given server.

Note that your browser can only save what the web server sent it, which is often different than the files the server has on disk. For example, if a given page uses PHP, the file on disk on the web server has a bunch of PHP code in it that gets processed by the PHP interpreter on the server and stripped out / replaced before it's served to your browser. So even if the URL ends in .php, the file your browser gets sent will be missing a bunch of PHP code that the original .php file on the server contains. So since modern websites are almost never just an easily discovered set of static files, you can't make a working clone of someone else's website just by trying to use a web browser or other HTTP client to try to HTTP-download every resource you can find on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right path, but both HTTP and FTP can upload and download files.  They overlap a little on what they can do, but FTP has usually had a specific purpose for moving large files.  A FTP server must be set up and the client (you) must use a FTP software client to connect.  One popular free FTP software to look into is Filezilla.

HTTP and HTTPS, and newer versions such as SPDY and HTTP/2, are the default protocol used when browsing websites and do in fact download files from the web server to you computer.  Your web browser then takes these files and puts together a page for you see.  It's really amazing when you break down what's actually going on (syn, syn-ack, ack, request, response, fin, fin-ack, ack commands between your browser and the server)  when simply opening a website such as the BBC.